# Dynamic Catch of Server Errors with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, error-handling

my answer is quite simple:
Is there a way to catch server-errors (like Error 400, 401, 403, 404, 500...) automatically with PHP and generate **custom** Error-Pages.

For example, let's say I got a PHP-File with the page and it just inserts the Error-Code and the Error-Message.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use set_error_handler. see http://php.net/manual/pl/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: yes.. use htaccess for doing that..

Comment: You will have to catch those errors in the level of the http server, not inside php. That is very well possible, you can register "custom error handlers" inside for example the apache http server. Such handlers can even invoke php scripts, no problem there. Take a look at the documentation of the http server. This is all well documented and explained.

Comment: @arkascha I took a look into that, it's really too complicated for just Error-Messages. However, you where the only one that understood my Problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is complicated about that? It is a single command in your host configuration...

Comment: Then I might have searched in the wrong place, which host configuration do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You may use custom [exception handler function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) (`set_exception_handler()`) and [error handler](http://php.net/function.set_error_handler) (`set_error_handler()`) for turn errors to Exception ([example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#65203))

Comment: Exception and error handlers in PHP don't matter for true HTTP errors.  It will never reach a PHP application unless you specify the web server to redirect requests to the PHP application so this answer is incomplete, but the question is probably too broad.

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

`404` here is your error code and `/404.html` is your redirection file when error occurs.
here goes your tutorial..
http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/custom-error-pages-using-htaccess